# Is it kufr or not?

Tags: shirk, kufr

i got a question. i have a friend who told me she doesnt know if she did kufr or not. i really want to help her but im not sure about the answer

well she said when she was at the age 12-13 she said once she loved Shaytaan and when she got older she suddenly regretted what she said. she knew what she did was very very wrong. Well she did umrah and asked Allah forgiveness to forgive her past mistakes and she never said it again. she still regrets it this day did she did kufr or not?